# Cannot get environment vars in Java when declared in separate file

Tags: java, bash, macos, unix, environment-variables

Im on macOS. Im adding custom environmental variables to `.bash_profile` e.g.

```
export EMONEY_AUTHORIZATION=abc123
```

This works fine and I can get these in my Java code with:

```
System.getenv("EMONEY_AUTHORIZATION")
```

However I have many variables to add, so I added them all to a new file called `my_env_vars`:

```
export EMONEY_AUTHORIZATION=abc123
export EMONEY_USERNAME=user@mydomain.com
```

And then in `.bash_profile`:

```
source "my_env_vars"
```

Now I can get these variables through the command line, but not through java, somehow. Why is this?

Comment: Perhaps the java program is running from a different directory. Does `source $HOME/my_env_vars` help?

Comment: Can you post how you're trying to get these env vars from within Java? And how exactly are you running your Java code?